# Eclipse RCP: How to notify the UI thread

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse-rcp, inputstream

I have a background thread which reads data from java.io.InputStream:

```
while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
    // ...
    if (is.available()==0) {
        // Need to update UI
    }
}
```

When is.available()=0, I need to update UI. I tried to do it this way:

```
if (is.available()==0) {
    view.updateState();
}
```

and the logic of view.updateState():

```
public void updateState() {
    Display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        // UI logic
    });
}
```

This does not work because when is.available()=0, the input stream blocks (waiting for input from System.in). At this moment, the UI thread is also in waiting state. How can I notify the UI thread to read and dispatch? Is it safe to notify the UI thread when the input stream is blocking? Thanks

Here is the test result.
Expected: When view.updateState() is called, the input buttons on the view should be enabled by executing the logic inside Display.asyncExec()
Actual: The input buttons are not enabled and program hung there

Comment: The UI thread 'waiting state' is already in `readAndDispatch` so it is ready to do any `asyncExec` it receives. So I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added the test result. Looks like another deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. Display.asyncExec() works fine. For some reason is.available() returns 0 twice in the while loop before it blocks.